# Sorting an Array by Row Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say for example, I have an Array:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],
["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Sliver"],
[25, 50, 10, 0, 5, 100]]
```

How would I sort this data into ascending order of row 3?

For example

```
[[4,5,3,1,2,6],
["Yellow", "Black", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Sliver"],
[0, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]]
```

Comment: Please show what have you done so far and refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you explain how the second subarray is ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Sliver"],
  [25, 50, 10, 0, 5, 100]
];

// Giving an array arr swap the values of indexes i and j
function swap(arr, i, j) {
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
}

// the array which will be sorted you can choose anyone here (more flexible that way)
var theArr = myArray[2];

// sort theArr
for (var i = 0, len = theArr.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
  // assume minIndex is the first
  var minIndex = i;
  // check if there is something lesser than whatever in minIndex
  for (var j = minIndex + 1; j < len; j++) {
    // if so ...
    if (theArr[minIndex] > theArr[j])
    // minIndex becomes this index (j)
      minIndex = j;
  }

  // now that we found our minIndex lets swap minIndex value with i value for all the sub-arrays of myArray
  myArray.forEach(function(subArr) {
    swap(subArr, minIndex, i);
  });
}

console.log(myArray);
```

**NOTE:** `myArray` can have as much sub-arrays as you want (they just have to be of the same size of course). And you can sort according to whatever sub-array you want (`var theArr = myArray[/*desired sub-array index*/];` (It's more flexible that way).

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard function in many languages called `zip` that converts an array of rows into an array of columns, for example, if `a` is

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]
```

then `zip(a)` will be:

```
[ [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6] ]
```

JS has no built-in `zip`, but it's trivial to write:

```
let zip = a => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(r => r[i]));
```

With `zip` your problem can be solved in one line:

```
let result = zip(zip(data).sort((a, b) => a[2] - b[2]));
```

Basically, convert your rows to columns, sort these by the 3rd element and then convert back to rows.

Comment: please  can you provide some links for `zip`.? it is really interesting.

Comment: @Hekmat: sure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_(computer_science)

Comment: yea really nice concept.mapping a tuple of sequences into a sequence of tuples.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can first take order of last array form data that you want to sort by and put it in object and then sort by that object.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Sliver"],
  [25, 50, 10, 0, 5, 100]
]

var sortBy = arr[2].slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  r[i] = arr[2].indexOf(e)
  return r;
}, {})

arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  arr[i] = e.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    return sortBy[e.indexOf(a)] - sortBy[e.indexOf(b)]
  })
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort the last array to get the sorted map, then use this map to sort the corresponding other two arrays.

Modified @Nenad code to get the expected output.

```
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Sliver"],
  [25, 50, 10, 0, 5, 100]
]

let sortBy = arr[2].slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((r, e, i) =>{
  r[i] = arr[2].indexOf(e)
  return r;
}, {})


let x = arr.map( (e)  =>{
   return( e.slice().sort( (a, b) =>{
    return sortBy[e.indexOf(a)] - sortBy[e.indexOf(b)]
  })
  )
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
```